# ¿Como eliminar las filas en blanco al momento de Importar un Excel a un DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Tengo un `Button` el cual manda a llamar un Archivo de Excel y lo Importa en un `DataGridView`. Cabe destacar que no tengo ningún problema al importar. El detalle es que me me salen filas hasta el final vacías, sin datos... Para un mayor entendimiento les comparto un código el cual, sin mentir, lo saque del siguiente [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rdemh_8sBSc) .

El código del `Button` es el siguiente:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
    {
       Filter = "Excel | *.xls;*.xlsx;",

       Title = "Seleccionar Archivo"
    };

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       AgregarPagos.DataSource = ImportarDatos(openFileDialog.FileName);
    }
}
```

El método para Importar los Datos es el Siguiente:

```
    DataView ImportarDatos(string nombrearchivo)
    {
        string conexion = string.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {0}; Extended Properties = 'Excel 12.0;'", nombrearchivo);

        OleDbConnection conector = new OleDbConnection(conexion);

        conector.Open();

        OleDbCommand consulta = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Hoja1$]", conector);

        OleDbDataAdapter adaptador = new OleDbDataAdapter
        {
            SelectCommand = consulta
        };

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        adaptador.Fill(ds);

        conector.Close();

        return ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }
```

El resultado es:

[image: Captura de pantalla del DataGridView llenado]

De esos 3 registros que se muestras hacia arriba esta todo excelente... Lo que no quiero es que tenga de esos 3 hacia abajo las celdas en blanco.

Espero me puedan apoyar, De igual buscare una solución y si la encuentro se las estaré compartiendo.

Comment: Pon el enlace de tu archivo excel para poder probarlo.

Comment: Lo hace con cualquier archivo, Abre una ventana para buscar el archivo que quieras Importar. Aunque es indispensable contar con AccessDatabaseEngine. Por que si no genera un error.

Comment: Ok, en seguida te envío la respuesta

Comment: @JesusDanielVazquezLorenzo, [mira esto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5025983/8933039), usando una condición `Where`, puede que te funcione si lo aplicas a tu función. O probar las demás soluciones propuestas, filtrando los datos luego de cargado... `dataTable = dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(row => !row.ItemArray.All(field => field is System.DBNull || string.Compare((field as string).Trim(), string.Empty) == 0)).CopyToDataTable();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataView ImportarDatos(string nombrearchivo)
    {
        string conexion = string.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {0}; Extended Properties = 'Excel 12.0;'", nombrearchivo);

        OleDbConnection conector = new OleDbConnection(conexion);

        conector.Open();

        OleDbCommand consulta = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Hoja1$]", conector);

        OleDbDataAdapter adaptador = new OleDbDataAdapter
        {
            SelectCommand = consulta
        };

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        adaptador.Fill(ds);

        conector.Close();

        //ADICIONA ESTO
        ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.ItemArray.All(field => field == null || field == DBNull.Value || field.Equals(string.Empty) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field.ToString()))).ToList().ForEach(row => row.Delete());
        ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();

        return ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }
```

Comment: Excelente, Intentaba hacerlo mediante la misma consulta. Pero funciono perfectamente lo que dices. Muchas Grcias.

Comment: De nada, que tengas un excelente día